# Why does the condition that a multifunction is lower semi-continuous ($F(cl \ A) \subset cl \ F(A)$) fail here?

Tags: functions, continuity

Let's say I take a multifunction which goes like this:

$$f(x) = x^2 \chi_{x\le a} + (x^2 + 1) \chi_{x > a}$$

Let's say, I take $b > a$ and let's define $c := a^2$, $d_1 := (a^2 + 1)$ and $d_2 := (b^2 + 1)$

It's clear that

$$f((a,b)) = (d_1, d_2)$$

So this means, that

$$cl \ f((a,b)) = [ d_1, d_2 ]$$

It's also clear, that

$$f([a,b]) = \{ c \} \cup (d_1, d_2]$$

Function $f(x)$ is lower semi-continuous. So it should hold, that

$$f (cl \ (a,b)) \subset cl \ f ((a,b))$$

But it's not the case here!

$$\{c\} \cup (d_1, d_2] \not\subset [d_1, d_2]$$

So what's wrong here?

Comment: What is a multifunction?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos A multifunction is a relation $F \subset X \times Y$ such that for every $x \in X$ we have $F(x) = \{ y \in Y \ | \ (x,y) \subset F \} \neq \varnothing$

Comment: But your $f$ as an ordinary *function*, right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, but every ordinary function is a multifunction, right? A multifunction is just like an ordinary function, but with the exception that for every $x \in X$ you can assign $k$ $y$ values (in the case of an ordinary function how we know it, it's just a multifunction with $k = 1$ here, you can only assign one $y$ value for every $x$). So this property that a multifunction is lower semi-continuous $(F(cl \ A) \subset cl \ F(A))$ should still hold for ordinary functions, too, right?

Comment: I just think that it is strange that you call $f$ a multifunction, since it is an ordinary function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It's a special case of a multifunction in my understanding. So why does this condition for lower semi-continuity not hold here for $f(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $f$ is lower semi-continuous. That means that, if $\tau$ is the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ and $\lambda$ is the topology on $\Bbb R$ generated by the intervals of the form $(a,\infty)$ ($a\in\Bbb R$), then $f$ is continuous as a function from $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ into $(\Bbb R,\lambda)$. And, in $(\Bbb R,\lambda)$,$$\overline{f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)}=\overline{(d_1,d_2)}=(-\infty,d_2].$$Since $c\in(-\infty,d_2]$, there is no contradiction here.

Comment: Why do we have $$\overline{(d_1, d_2)} = (- \infty, d_2)$$

Comment: I meant to write that $\overline{(d_1,d_2)}=(−\infty,d_2]$, which is true, since $(−\infty,d_2]$ is the smallest closed set which contains $(d_1,d_2)$.